# how to create a Dataframe (multi-index) with sub-columns from a nested Dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I tried to create two sub-columns under one column. First I created a DataFrame from a Dictionary

```py
Destination = ['Milan', 'London','Lisbon','Milan','Mumbai', 'Lisbon', 'Porto', 'Lisbon']
Product_Revenue = [542,332,135,524,232, 522, 122, 122]

data_frame = {'Destination' : [i for i in Destination], 
                            'Revenue': [j for j in Product_Revenue]}
pd.DataFrame(data_frame)
```

Second, I wanted to add `Booking` as the main column so that `Destination` and `Revenue` becomes sub-column of it. But I got `Destination` and `Revenue` in the index and even as a list.

```py
data_frame = {'Booking': {'Destination' : [i for i in Destination], 
                            'Revenue': [j for j in Product_Revenue]}}
pd.DataFrame(data_frame)
```

```
                             Booking

Destination    [Milan, London, Vienna, Milan, Mumbai, Paris, ...


Revenue     [542, 332, 135, 524, 232, 522, 122, 122]
```

The `Destination` and `Revenue` is showing in rows.

How can I write each value of both in parallel as the previous one?

A future goal is to add `Users` as the index. So, the final dataframe would be `User` Vs `Booking` Data where `Destination` and `Price` values would vary for each user.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to perform a list comprehension when passing to the dataframe constructor. Just pass the lists themselves. For example: `pd.DataFrame({'Destination': Destination, 'Revenue': Product_Revenue})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing. If you are looking to build a DF with columns as multiindex where the first level is 'Booking' and the second level is [Destination, Revenue], the keys should be defined as tuples:

```
Destination = ['Milan', 'London','Lisbon','Milan','Mumbai', 'Lisbon', 'Porto', 'Lisbon']
Product_Revenue = [542,332,135,524,232, 522, 122, 122]

data_frame = {('Booking', 'Destination') : Destination, 
              ('Booking', 'Revenue'): Product_Revenue}

pd.DataFrame(data_frame)
```

Output:

```
Booking
Destination Revenue
0   Milan   542
1   London  332
2   Lisbon  135
3   Milan   524
4   Mumbai  232
5   Lisbon  522
6   Porto   122
7   Lisbon  122
```

Comment: This absolutely solves my first and main part. This is for user_1. Now, if I consider I have 5 different users with different booking details, should I use multi-index or create separate dataframes for each and then merge()?